# Enqueueing IE conditional stylesheets in WordPress correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I've been trying to follow a tutorial that shows how to correctly enqueue stylesheets in the Wordpress functions folder, and how to set up Internet Explorer stylesheets to overwrite/ add the necessary components for compatibility with older browsers. There are two methods of doing this to the tutorial, the second of which is an update for the first method, which has since become outdated.

Here's the link: https://gist.github.com/wpscholar/4947518

The first method uses global styles, and I can get this one to work using the code below:

```
function enqueue_my_styles_and_scripts() {

global $wp_styles;

if (is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php')) 
    { wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-full-page' , 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/full-page.css');      
} 

else { wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style_ie8', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/ie8.css', array( 'theme_style' ) ); 
    $wp_styles->add_data( 'theme_style_ie8', 'conditional', 'IE 8' ); 

    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style_ie9', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/ie9.css', array( 'theme_style' ) ); 
    $wp_styles->add_data( 'theme_style_ie9', 'conditional', 'IE 9' ); 
} }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles_and_scripts' );
```

The second method uses wp_styles. The article states that the former method is outdated and that the second method is now the best way to do it. I've followed the this part of the tutorial and this is what I came up with. For some reason it completely ignores my I.E stylesheets, and I'm not sure why. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I'd really rather use the most up-to-date method rather than an old one that could potentially cause issues later. Can anyone see what might be the problem with this code?

```
function enqueue_my_styles_and_scripts() {  

if (is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php')) 
    { wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-full-page' , 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/full-page.css');      
} 

else { wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style_ie8', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/ie8.css', array( 'theme_style' ) ); 
    wp_style_add_data( 'theme_style_ie8', 'conditional', 'lt IE 8' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style_ie9', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/ie9.css', array( 'theme_style' ) ); 
    wp_style_add_data( 'theme_style_ie9', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

} }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles_and_scripts' );
```

Comment: When you say "completely ignore", do you mean nothing is being output in the HTML source?

Comment: Hi Tim, I just checked and they're still coming up in the page source on firefox and chrome. I can't check on internet explorer as I'm running it on crossbrowsertesting.com

Comment: Ok. So what do you mean by completely ignore?

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear – none of the css in my IE stylesheets work in Internet Explorer when I have add the second code example above, yet they still show up in view source.

Comment: Ok, so they're added to the source, but IE is not loading them with your second example. That means there must be a difference in the source code between the two examples. Have you compared those?

Comment: I think I've worked out what was stopping the stylesheets from working. When I pasted the code from that tutorial, I didn't notice the 'lt' in the `'lt IE 9'`part. I'm taking a guess that it stands for 'later than'. Anyway I've removed it and it seems to be working :)

Comment: There you go :) Glad you solved it!

Comment: Oh btw @Jack1991 - forgot to say, lt is for less than

Comment: Oh I see, thanks Tim :)